# SelectNodes using sum condition XPATH C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, sum

i am trying to make some query that returns the TV-shows that have more than the amount of epidods in all its seasons.
i have function that get XMLDoc and amount.

i tried to do this but something getting wrong:

```
   public XmlNodeList Query7(XmlDocument xmlDoc, int amountOfEpisodes)// 
            {
                string s = "Netflix/TV-shows/TV-show[sum(seasons)>"+amountOfEpisodes+"]";
                XmlNodeList xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(s);
                return xmlNodeList;
            }
```

XMLDoc:

```
<Netflix>
  <TV-shows>
    <TV-show>
          <name>Game of Thrones</name>
          <genre>Action</genre>
          <year>2011</year>
          <seasons>
            <season>
              <episodes>10</episodes>
            </season>
            <season>
              <episodes>10</episodes>
            </season>
            <season>
              <episodes>10</episodes>
            </season>
            <season>
              <episodes>10</episodes>
            </season>
            <season>
              <episodes>10</episodes>
            </season>
            <season>
              <episodes>10</episodes>
            </season>
            <season>
              <episodes>7</episodes>
            </season>
          </seasons>
        </TV-show>
        <TV-show>
          <name>The Sopranos</name>
          <genre>Crime</genre>
          <year>1999</year>
          <seasons>
            <season>
              <episodes>13</episodes>
            </season>
            <season>
              <episodes>13</episodes>
            </season>
            <season>
              <episodes>13</episodes>
            </season>
            <season>
              <episodes>13</episodes>
            </season>
            <season>
              <episodes>13</episodes>
            </season>
            <season>
              <episodes>21</episodes>
            </season>
          </seasons>
        </TV-show>
        <TV-show>
 </TV-shows>
</Netflix>
```

for example in my XML above for the input "70" the result should to be only
"The Sopranos" because sum of episodes above 70 is only in The Sopranos.

thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

Your xpath doesn't work because sum(seasons) doesn't mean anything as seasons isn't a number. You could get the count of seasons with count(seasons) but that isn't what you're looking for. Instead, you want the sum of episodes so you need to select the episodes:

/Netflix/Tv-shows/TV-show[sum(seasons/season/episodes)>"+amountOfEpisodes+"]"

Comment: Just wanted to submit the same answer. You were faster :-)

Comment: Thank you! works! i have another question. there is exist in XML distinct command?

Comment: Depends on what version of xpath you're limited to. They added the distinct-values function in 2.0: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-distinct-values

Comment: if for example i select some actors and  there are duplicate last name , how can i use distinct here?  //actors/actor[year-of-birth>'" + yearOfBirth + "'][count(awards/award)>"+amountOfAwards+"]/last-name";

Comment: @DavidZaltsman if you have another question, ask it as a new question, not as a comment on the answer to a previous question.

Answer (score -1):

Use xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var results = doc.Descendants("TV-show").Select(x => new
            {
                name = (string)x.Element("name"),
                episodes = x.Descendants("episodes").Count()
            }).ToList();


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Downvoting because I think when someone asks for a solution in a specified language (XPath), giving a solution in a different language is off-topic and not an answer, unless there are very good and well-explained reasons for advising a different technology. Also, my interpretation of the question is that the OP wants the sum of the `episodes` element values, not the count of  `episodes` elements.